# Visual Studio crashes and restarts without error message

Tags: visual-studio, crash, visual-studio-2019

when I click around in Solution Explorer or just write code (without executing anything) Visual Studio starts to stop responding and restarts the project.
With no error message nothing. It just restarts after not responding.

This happens after I open the project after 2-5 minutes .
Tried it on a brand new created project as well. Same problem.

Do you have any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing in VS 2019 _16.9.0 Preview 2.0_.  I don't know if it is related to SQL Server Database Tool (SSDT) projects, WPF or some add-in

Comment: I have now found the source of the error. The software eXtraButtons has caused the crash. I have terminated the software and now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the whole package and install it again.

Comment: I have already done that. This did not solve the problem

Comment: Though it begs the question - _what “package”?_